# Translate javascript POST request into Axios (using Stripe)

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, stripe-payments, axios

I am working with Stripe (developing a payment system) on React.js and I am trying to translate the code below into React.js and use axios to create the endpoint that receives the POST request from the backend (Django):

```js
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: 'pk_test_zNq2YI8Spsyi81TknNujN36T',
  image: 'https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
  locale: 'auto',
  token: function(token) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'http://localhost:8000/subscriptions/codes/pay/',
      data: {amount: amount, token: token},
    });
  }
});
```

I am stuck on Step 4 from this link : [Stripe for React](https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/elements-react), which explains the POST request but they are using Express, and I am using Django.

Answer (score 0):

The server side code can be written in any language/frameworks as long as it provides an endpoint `subscriptions/codes/pay/` for your front-end post.

In `Django`, you can refer to the document at [0] on how to get started on creating a REST API

A very simple code

define your route

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('subscriptions/checkout', views.ElementView.as_view(), name="Stripe Checkout"),
    path('subscriptions/codes/pay', views.charge, name='charge'),
]
```

And in your view definitions

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@require_http_methods(["POST"])
@csrf_exempt
def charge(request):
    # request.body will contain your data {amount: amount, token: token}
    return HttpResponse(request.body)
```

Again, the backend implementation should be language/framework agnostic; it will work as long as your backend provide a valid `POST` API allowing you to send your StripeToken back

[0] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/